# Convert DateTimeOffset from SQL Server to DateTime in VBA

Tags: vba, datetime

How can I convert DateTimeOffset to DateTime in Access VBA.
I'm pulling in rows from SQL Server using an ADODB.RecordSet.  But the values appear as rubbish '?93'

I'm copying them to a  local table field for field, so can't do any conversion in SQL Server.

I've searched google, but can't find anything for VBA.

Comment: Anyone have an idea of how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

You must use a SQL Passthrough query. Convert your datetimeoffset column like so:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, [column_name]) AS [column_name]
```

This will give you the answer in the time using the offset. For UTC time, use this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, [column_name], 1) AS [column_name]
```